# How to pass data to a component when it renders in new window

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am rendering a component in new window using React router Link, now how to pass the data to this new component. The data i want to pass is JSON data so if i pass it as param or query its been displayed in URL.

So is there any other option available to pass the data while opening in new window?

Answer (score 2):

Use one of the newer options:

- localStorage
- IndexedDB
- postMessage (https://plnkr.co/edit/YrG1KNrc1CvLCp8A1ucG)

  ```
  <script>
  var popup = window.open('data:text/html;charset=utf-8;base64,PHNjcmlwdD5mdW5jdGlvbiByZWNlaXZlTWVzc2FnZShldmVudCkgeyBldmVudC5zb3VyY2UucG9zdE1lc3NhZ2UoImhpIHRoZXJlIHlvdXJzZWxmISB0aGUgc2VjcmV0IHJlc3BvbnNlIGlzOiAiICsgZXZlbnQuZGF0YSwgIioiKTsgY29uc29sZS5sb2coIldlIHJlY2VpdmVkIHRoZSBtZXNzYWdlOiAiICsgZXZlbnQuZGF0YSk7IH0gd2luZG93LmFkZEV2ZW50TGlzdGVuZXIoIm1lc3NhZ2UiLCByZWNlaXZlTWVzc2FnZSwgZmFsc2UpOzwvc2NyaXB0Pg==');

  function receiveMessage(event)
    {
    console.log("The message from the data:URI is: " + event.data );
    }

  function foo()
    {
    popup.postMessage("The user is 'bob' and the password is 'secret'", "*");
    popup.postMessage("hello there!", "*");
    }

  window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
  window.setTimeout(foo, 2000);
  </script>
  ```

**References**

- [Window.postMessage() - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)
- [Every known way to get references to windows in JavaScript](https://medium.com/@bluepnume/every-known-way-to-get-references-to-windows-in-javascript-223778bede2d)
- [How should I implement saving state to localStorage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43480207/how-should-i-implement-saving-state-to-localstorage)
- [Pull data from IndexedDB into array and output it via ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37273721/pull-data-from-indexeddb-into-array-and-output-it-via-reactjs)
- [Triggering Synthetic Event in React App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32132608/triggering-synthetic-event-in-react-app)
- [A technique for saving content from a data:text/html, URI](https://medium.com/@the_taqquikarim/a-technique-for-saving-content-from-a-data-text-html-uri-10f045a8876d)